# Converting an int array to printing the string associated with that array in Java

Tags: java

I need to print the name of the person with the highest votes, not the highest votes. Other than that, the program works fine. I have tried many different methods to no prevail and it is just that I want it working the simplest way.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //for user inputs
public class Election6 {
public static int SIZE = 5; //declares the size of the array globally
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner allows for user inputs
    String[] saNames = new String[SIZE];
```

Variables declared here

```
    int nIndex=0;
    int nSumVotes = 0;
    int nTotalV = 0;
    int nMaxVotes = 0;
    double dPercentVotes = 0.0;
```

Arrays declared here:

```
    //array and array length declared here
   int[] naVotes = new int[SIZE];

   double[] daPercent = new double[SIZE];
```

Votes array used here

```
   for (nIndex=0; nIndex<SIZE; nIndex ++){
   System.out.print("Please enter the candidate's name: ");
   saNames[nIndex] = input.next();

   System.out.print("Please enter the number of votes: ");
   naVotes[nIndex] = input.nextInt();

   System.out.println("");

   }
```

Calling a method here

```
   nSumVotes = sumVotes(naVotes);
```

I use this for statement to decide the max votes array it is just I cannot convert it into a string to then print the string variable to screen.

```
   for (int nIdx = 0; nIdx < SIZE; nIdx++){
       if (nMaxVotes < naVotes[nIdx]){;
            nMaxVotes = naVotes[nIdx];

       }
   }
```

This is the end of this for statement

```
   for (int nIndx = 0; nIndx < SIZE; nIndx++){          
            daPercent[nIndx] = ((double)naVotes[nIndx]/nSumVotes)*100;
       }




   System.out.println("Candidate  " +"Votes " + "Percentage ");
   for (int nCount1 = 0; nCount1 < SIZE; nCount1++){
       System.out.println(saNames[nCount1]  + "\t   " + naVotes[nCount1] + "\t " + daPercent[nCount1]+"%");           
   }


   System.out.println("Total\t   " + nSumVotes);
   System.out.println("");
```

I print the maxvotes on this line

```
System.out.println("The next Student Government President is " + 
nMaxVotes +".");
}//End of main

public static int sumVotes(int[] naTotalVotes){
    int nTotal = 0;
    int nCount = 0;
    for (nCount = 0; nCount < SIZE; nCount++){
        nTotal = nTotal + naTotalVotes[nCount];

    }
    return nTotal;
}//end of method


}//End of class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is so broken up it's difficult to understand fully, but I think this is where you can trap the index position of your candidate:

```
   for (int nIdx = 0; nIdx < SIZE; nIdx++){
       if (nMaxVotes < naVotes[nIdx]){;
            nMaxVotes = naVotes[nIdx];

       }
   }
```

Maybe rewrite like this:

```
   for (int nIdx = 0; nIdx < SIZE; nIdx++){
       if (nMaxVotes < naVotes[nIdx]){;
            nMaxVotes = naVotes[nIdx];
            nWinningCandidate = saNames[nIdx];
       }
   }
```

Edit:
It seems to me a much more appropriate data structure would be a Map, so unless you have a billion candidates and a severe memory shortage, why wouldn't you use something that simplifies your code?